# How to fix horizontal line on my laptop screen?

Tags: acer-aspire

I have an acer aspire one d257. I noticed a horizontal line on my laptop screen yesterday. The horizontal line changes color depending on the color of the screen. On a white background, it changes to blue. On a black background, it changes to red. When i put pressure on my screen, it doesn't go away. If i adjust the laptop screen to open and close, it doesn't go away. Can anybody tell me what I can do to fix this? Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

Check any connectors for lose fitting. Replace the LCD/LED panel.